# How can I render a component into an Angular modal?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to render a component into a Angular dialog. This component is used on on a full page of my application and it has children.
When I add the selector into my modal, I've got an error : ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

This error happens on the page which loads the modal.

Is it possible to reuse a component into an Angular modal with his inputs and outputs ?

```html
<!-- modal -->

<ng-container>
  <div class="close-button-wrapper">
    <button (click)="onCloseClick()" mat-icon-button>
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="dialog-content">
    <picture-container></picture-container>  <!-- not working  ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError -->
  </div>

  <div class="dialog-footer">
    <raised-button-round class="action-button">Cancel</raised-button-round>
    <raised-button-round icon="save" color="primary" class="action-button">OK</raised-button-round>
  </div>
</ng-container>


<!-- component I want to reuse -->

@Component({
  selector: 'picture-container',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
      <picture-presenter
        [images]="data.pictures"
        [tagImages]="data.tagImages"
        [totalCountItems]="data.totalCountItems"
        [tags]="data.tags"
        [pageSize]="20"
        [isSelectablePicture]="data.isSelectablePicture"
        (displayableContent)="onChangeDisplay($event)"
        (searchTagSelect)="onSearchTagSelect($event)"
        (importPicture)="onImportPicture()"
        (pictureAction)="onPictureAction($event)"
        (changePage)="pageChange$.next($event)"
      ></picture-presenter>
    </ng-container>
    <upload-widget #uploadWidget (upload)="onUpload($event)"></upload-widget>
  `,
  styles: [``],
})
export class PictureContainerComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  @ViewChild('uploadWidget') uploadWidget?: UploadWidgetComponent
  data$: Observable<
    Maybe<{
      pictures: Maybe<PictureFragment>[]
      tagImages: TagImage[]
      tags: Maybe<{ name: string; count: number }>[]
      totalCountItems: number,
      isSelectablePicture: boolean
    }>
  > = of(null)
  destroyed$ = new Subject<boolean>()
  pageChange$ = new BehaviorSubject<PaginatorEvent>({})
  personalImages$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true)
  searchTags$ = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([])

  constructor(public store: Store) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    combineLatest([
      this.store.select(selectStore),
      this.store.select(selectGalleries),
      this.searchTags$,
      this.pageChange$,
      this.personalImages$,
      this.store.select(selectPictureUpdated),
    ])
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe(
        ([store, galleries, tags, direction, isPersonal, picUpdated]) => {
          if (!galleries) return
          // TODO - High - Get right gallery
          const galleriesId = galleries.map((gal) => gal?.id || '')
          const filters = {
            galleries: !isPersonal ? galleriesId : [],
            tags: !isPersonal ? tags : [],
            owner: store?.id,
          }

          this.store.dispatch(
            loadPictures({
              filters,
              paginate: {
                count: 15,
              },
              paginatorEvent: direction,
              noCache: picUpdated != null ? true : false,
            })
          )

          this.store.dispatch(
            loadTags({
              search: {
                galleries: galleriesId,
                owner: store?.id,
              },
            })
          )

        }
      )

    this.data$ = combineLatest([
      this.store.select(selectPicturesState),
      of(TAG_IMAGES),
      this.store.select(selectPagination),
      this.store.select(selectTags),
      this.store.select(selectIsSelectablePicture),
    ]).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
      map(([picturesState, tagImages, pagination, tags, isSelectablePicture]) => {
        return {
          pictures: picturesState?.pictures || [],
          tagImages,
          totalCountItems: pagination?.totalCount || 0,
          tags,
          isSelectablePicture
        }
      })
    )
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroyed$.next(true)
    this.destroyed$.complete()
  }

  onSearchTagSelect(tags: string[]) {
    this.pageChange$.next({})
    this.searchTags$.next(tags)
  }

  onImportPicture() {
    if (this.uploadWidget) {
      this.uploadWidget?.openDialog({ pictureType: 'food' })
    }
  }

  onPictureAction($event: {
    picture: Maybe<PictureFragment>
    action: 'edit' | 'delete'
  }) {
    if (!$event.picture) return
    const picture = parsePictureFragmentToPictureInput($event.picture)
    if (!picture) return
    if ($event.action === 'edit') {
      this.store.dispatch(
        setUpdatePicture({
          picture,
        })
      )
    } else {
      this.store.dispatch(setDeletePicture({ picture }))
    }
  }

  onUpload($event: any) {
    this.store.select(selectStore).subscribe((store) => {
      this.store.dispatch(
        setUploadPicture({
          picture: { ...$event, owner: store?.id },
        })
      )
    })
  }

  onChangeDisplay($event: 'import' | 'suggestions' | 'search') {
    this.personalImages$.next($event !== 'search')
  }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you know the reason for `ExpressionChangedAfterChecked`? Have you read and watched https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

Comment: I already read the documentation you provide. I know there is a problem, but my question is more about how can I reuse a component ?

Comment: You can reuse the component that way. The problem is somewhere else. You have to find the problem and fix it. Usually it has something to do with changing a parent property in a child component. The problem is unrelated to reusing components. Reusing a component at different places is the whole concept of components.

Comment: Ok got it, thank you. I just need to find the ExpressionChangedAfterChecked error and I'll understand what happens.

Comment: Yes, and the link in my first comment helps you to identify the actual problem.

Comment: Yes I found the problem but it wasn't into the code above. I just looked up for previous commits and I finally found. Thanks for your help :)